# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Counter' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, string, file

Here is my code

```
    #word count2
from collections import Counter
def main():
    with open("search words.txt","r") as myfile:
         data=myfile.read()
         topTenWords(data)


def topTenWords(wordCountDict):
    split_it=wordCountDict.split()
    Counter = Counter(split_it)
    most_common=Counter.most_common(10)
    print(most_common)

if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

then upon running the above code I am getting error

```
word count2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/word count2.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/word count2.py", line 6, in main
    topTenWords(data)
  File "D:/word count2.py", line 11, in topTenWords
    Counter = Counter(split_it)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Counter' referenced before assignment
```

What is the mistake in above code?

Comment: will you change `Counter = Counter(split_it)` to `counter = Counter(split_it)` and also change `Counter.most_common(10)` to `counter.most_common(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should works:

```
# coding:utf-8
from collections import Counter


def main():
    with open("../docs/words.txt", "r") as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
        topTenWords(data)
def topTenWords(wordCountDict):
    split_it = wordCountDict.split()
    counter = Counter(split_it)
    most_common = counter.most_common(10)
    print(most_common)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the imported Counter Class with a variable. 
Just write for example `counter = Counter(split_it)` and it should work.

Also just btw, you might wanna read the PEP8 Style Guide for Python, usually you don't use variable names that start with capital letters.